# One time password generation in express js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express

I am trying to generate OTP in  express js using speakeasy https://www.npmjs.com/package/speakeasy.

Here  is the sample code i've tried

```
var speakeasy = require('speakeasy');
        var secret = speakeasy.generateSecret({length:32});

        //generate token
        var code = speakeasy.totp({
            secret:secret.base32,
            encoding: 'base32',
            step:300,
            window:100,
            counter:123
        });

        //verify token
        var verified = speakeasy.totp.verify({
            secret:secret.base32 ,
            encoding: 'base32',
            token: code
        });
```

When verify the token `console.log(verified)` always return false.

I've followed this github link https://github.com/speakeasyjs/speakeasy/issues/52  but it didn't help

Comment: Here is a demo.. Checkout this, https://sedemo-mktb.rhcloud.com/

Comment: Same code is used but verified returns false

Comment: Have you tried adding `window: 2` option to your `verify` function.

Comment: Added but it didn't worked

Answer (score 3):

```
module.exports = (num = 4) => {
    return Math.random().toFixed(num).substr(`-${num}`)
}
```

### Edit:.substr is deprecated

`.substr` is now [deprecated][1]. We can use this approach instead:

```
module.exports = (num = 4) => {
     Math.random().toFixed(num).substring(0, length);
}
```

OTP: 9749

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about `speakeasy`, but we've successfully used `notp` in our project to generate one-time passwords we use with Express, maybe this might help : https://www.npmjs.com/package/notp

Comment: could you please update with code samples,documentation doesn't provide enough informations

Comment: Now i got a working sample ,but how can increase the token expiration time

Comment: Have a look at the `opt` config object here : [link](https://github.com/guyht/notp#totpverifytoken-key-opt)
`
import { totp } from 'notp';
const code = totp.gen(user.oathKey, otpOptions);
const isCodeValid = totp.verify(code, user.oathKey, otpOptions);
`

Answer (score 1):

Add `step` value given while generating token for verify.

```
var verified = speakeasy.totp.verify({
        secret:secret.base32 ,
        encoding: 'base32',
        token: code,
        step: 300
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be added `counter = 123` into verify function:

```
var verified = speakeasy.totp.verify({
      secret: secret.base32,
      encoding: 'base32',
      token: code, 
      counter: 123
});
```